How to fix the first value in a time series data
My questions here are quite simple, as I am a beginner.  I have the following problems.
I have a 2-day stock price data with 7 Time Points, i.e. 14 rows. DataFrame columns are DATE, Time_IDX, and Price, i.e. 3 columns. Time_IDX = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], which repeats daily.  There are 14 Prices, for example, df['Price'] = [288, 298, 301, 289, 300, 287, 295, 302, 305, 310, 299, 300, 285, 290].  I would like to create a variable called df['Price_0'] = [288,288,288,288,288,288,288,302,302,302,302,302,302,302].  This problem seems quite simple, but I have gotten into so many problems.
I have been struggling over creating a new column, daily df['Beg_Price'], showing the Beginning Price for Time_IDX = 1; and all other remaining 6 prices are identical to this Beg_Price.
I would really appreciate it if someone sees what beginners often miss when coding.  Thanks.
I tried groupby with DATE, or Time_IDX; and with loc method.  I also tried by setting indexes with Time_IDX as well.  However, the number in the df is not unique, and so I failed.  Thanks.

Please provide your input as an explicit DataFrame constructor, it is currently ambiguous

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

IIUC, you can groupby the Date and transform using the first value of Price:
df = pd.DataFrame({
  'Date' : ['2024-04-23']*7 + ['2024-04-24']*7,
  'Time_IDX': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]*2,
  'Price': [288, 298, 301, 289, 300, 287, 295, 302, 305, 310, 299, 300, 285, 290] 
})

df['Price_0'] = df.groupby('Date')['Price'].transform('first')

Output:
          Date  Time_IDX  Price  Price_0
0   2024-04-23         1    288      288
1   2024-04-23         2    298      288
2   2024-04-23         3    301      288
3   2024-04-23         4    289      288
4   2024-04-23         5    300      288
5   2024-04-23         6    287      288
6   2024-04-23         7    295      288
7   2024-04-24         1    302      302
8   2024-04-24         2    305      302
9   2024-04-24         3    310      302
10  2024-04-24         4    299      302
11  2024-04-24         5    300      302
12  2024-04-24         6    285      302
13  2024-04-24         7    290      302

